# Given a point $P$ in regular tetrahedron $T$, is there a triangle with vertices on the boundary of $T$ whose center of mass is $P$?

Tags: geometry, triangles, barycentric-coordinates, triangle-centres

Here's a "simple'' problem in basic geometry.

> Given is a regular tetrahedron $T$.
>
> Consider the Barycentric coordinate system on $T$.
> Given is also a point $P\in T$ in the interior of $T$ such that no two barycentric coordinates of $P$ are equal. ($P$ is not part of any half-plane of symmetry of $T$.)
>
> Does there exist a triangle $\Delta\subset T$ with both of the following properties?
>
> 1. The vertices of $\Delta$ are in the boundary of $T$
> 2. $P$ is the center of mass of $\Delta$

I think that there's a unique such triangle $\Delta$.
Furthermore, I feel that this should (somehow!!) generalize to simplexes of greater dimension. [I'm pretty sure it holds for a triangle $T$ and a line segment $\Delta$.]

Intelligenti pauca shows below that there's more than one such triangle. Great!

Here's a more complicated version, which I hope has a unique solution (due to fewer degrees of freedom).

Does there exists a plane $\pi\subset\mathbb R^3$ such that $P$ is the centroid of $\pi\cap T$?
(If so, then $P\in\pi$.
$\pi\cap T$ is a triangle $\Delta\subset T$ such that all vertices of $\Delta$ are part of an edge of $T$.)

All help is much appreciated, Jürgen

Comment: 1/ Can you state the allegedly unique triangle? $\quad$ 2/ It seems to me that use of barycentric coordinates isn't important. You just want to ignore the half plane of symmetry right?

Comment: @CalvinLin
1) I mean if you let $T$ be a triangle instead of a tetrahedron and $\Delta$ be a line instead of a triangle. That is, $T$ and $\Delta$ have their "dimensions" reduced by one. Then you can a unique such line $\Delta$.
2) Yes, that's what they are there for. I thought it would be more easily expressed like that. I know that one dimension below ($T$ a triangle and $\Delta$ a line), there are multiple solutions, if $P$ is part of an axes of symmetry.

Comment: 1/ Great, add that context in, esp the proof of uniqueness.   Now, try to extend that up a dimension. What you'd find is that it introduces a significant amount of slack (dimension) into the equations, and you don't necessarily end up with a unique triangle (or so I claim).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your updated question: do you also require $\pi\cap T$ to be a triangle, or not?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a geometric construction of the desired triangle (see figure below). As it was predictable (six free coordinates with three equations) we have three degrees of freedom left, hence the triangle is far from being unique.

Let $ABCD$ be the given tetrahedron and $P$ a given point inside it. We want to construct a triangle $QRS$ having $P$ as centroid and its vertices on faces $ABD$, $ABC$ and $ACD$ (we can choose any three faces at will). Start by choosing an arbitrary point on one of the faces, for instance point $S$ on $ACD$. Join $SP$ and extend it to $M$, such that $PS=2PM$. Point $M$ is then the midpoint of side $QR$ of the triangle.

Construct then $E$ on $AB$ as the perpendicular projection of $M$; from it draw line $EJ\perp AB$ on face $ABD$. Choose $J$ such that $MJ\perp EJ$ and extend $EJ$ to $L$ so that $EJ=JL$. Finally, from $L$ construct a line parallel to $AB$: any point $Q$ on that line can be chosen as the second vertex of the triangle, while the third vertex $R$ is the reflection of $Q$ about $M$.

[Here's the construction made with GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/m/x24jvete)

[image]

The construction works because $R$ lies on face $ABC$. In fact we can construct on $ABC$ point $K$ such that $EKMJ$ is a parallelogram, and point $N$ such that $K$ is the midpoint of $EN$. Point $N$ is then the reflection of $L$ about $M$ and line $NR$ is parallel to $LQ$, lying thus on $ABC$.

The construction fails if points $M$ or $R$ lie outside the tetrahedron, but we can avoid that with a different choice of points $S$ and $Q$, or changing the face where $S$ lies.

Comment: In fact, from point $M$, take any plane that cuts the other 3 sides of the tetrahedron, and we end up in the 2-D case. At least one such triangle exists (unique only if M doesn't lie on a median), and so we found a construction. Vary the plane, and we get a whole ton of constructions for the same point $S$.